# what's the best way to find a mac by name from windows?

Tags: windows, macos, networking, bonjour, zeroconf

I'm used to bonjour from mac. I'm hoping there is an easy way for windows machines (v. 7) to find my mac using a resolvable name.

This needs to be done by a browser.

I'd like as little setup as possible. I can configure mac or windows, but would prefer to make my mac available to multiple windows machines.

I am somewhat aware of zeroconf and dns-sd, but I was unable to determine what I need to do to make this work. Some suggestions seem to indicate that I would need to install dns-sd and then a plugin for firefox etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows CMD, type "arp -a" and press enter. This only works for the local network.

If you need this to be done in browser... can you run a local-network web server?

(LAMP or something?)

If so, put this into a PHP file...

```
<?php
echo '<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000"></body>'; 
echo '<pre>';
passthru("arp -a");
echo '</pre>';
?>
```